# How do I build my Maven pom in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, pom.xml

I have a project that uses UI4J, and instead of using external jar I decided to go for maven, I am going to distribute it via git, so I guessed that this is a much better approach.

This is my pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>Kalamaria</groupId>
  <artifactId>KalamariaHarverst</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>MavenFirst</name>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ui4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>ui4j</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

The problem is that I can't find a way to get this to work. What ever I try I am still getting errors on the import of the library, meaning that the jar of the ui4j is not imported.

I have (among others) tried to do a "Maven bumvn eclipse:eclipseild" with "clean install" as goal

Downloading source and Updating Project from the Maven menu
even tried to do a `mvn eclipse:eclipse` from the console, but i got this error

> The program 'mvn' can be found in the following packages:  * maven  *
>   maven2 Try: sudo apt-get install

How does this work, what should I do to import the declared jars?

Comment: Did you try to remove the <type></type> from your dependency? According to http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.ui4j/ui4j-api/2.0.0 there is no <type></type>

Comment: That was inserted automatically by m2e! now i get an error on the `<dependency>` line of pom saying `Missing artifact com.ui4j:ui4j:jar:2.0.0`

Comment: The console error is because you don't have the Maven binary (actually a shell script) on your command path. The dependency itself seems to be correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Removing `<type></type>` was the correct first step that you need to do.

Now, there's probably still a `pom.lastUpdated` file in your repository that is wrong, you need to forcibly override it. The easiest thing to do is just delete the entire directory in your `.m2` directory, which is located in your OS dependent home directory. On windows, this would be:

```
C:\Users\<username>\.m2\repository\com\ui4j
```

On Linux, this is usually in:

```
/home/<username>/.m2/repository/com/ui4j
```

Delete that directory, and then do Maven -> Update project, this should fix your problem.

By the way, `mvn eclipse:eclipse` is almost never the right thing to do, it's much better to use m2eclipse for your eclipse integrations as it works much more seamlessly.

---

I am not able to reproduce the behavior of the `pom` type being added automatically when you add the `ui4j` dependency. However, most of the time the correct dependency `<type>` is `jar`, as that is the default. `pom` dependencies are most often used when a project is simply a `pom` and nothing else, which is common as the parent `pom` of an entire application.

In this case (as in most cases), the type you want is `jar`, so don't specify a type parameter.

Comment: any idea where that might be on ubuntu?

Comment: Your answer provides the answer. It's the right answer, too. I just explain in a bit more depth why it works.

Comment: @Arkadiy That can be done as a comment or even as your own answer. Also, if my answer is correct why didn't you upvote it?

Comment: Upvoted. I just wanted the right answer to be better.

Comment: what i dont understand is why the type tag is wrong, or more precise, since it is wrong why was it inserted automatically when i added the dependency from the eclipse "add dependency" menu?

Comment: @Arkadiy Understandable, and your information is correct, but it's too substantial to be an edit to another's post. Edits are for "clarify[ing] the meaning of the post (**without changing that meaning**)", see: [Help/editing](http://stackoverflow.com/help/editing). I appreciate the intent to make my post better, but, in my opinion, the right thing to do is write your own answer that includes this information. Another option would be to comment the information, and give me the choice whether to incorporate it into my own answer.

Comment: @SkarosIlias Edited to answer that question.

Answer (score 0):

To add a bit more background to @durron597 's correct answer:

tag defines what Maven looks for in the repository when it downloads your artifact. Various types exist. Most common and default is "jar" - Maven will look for something packaged as "jar" - a regular *.jar file. Other types include "test-jar", "war" and "pom". Type "pom" means that Maven will look for something packaged as "pom" - basically your dependency's pom.xml file. Most of the artifacts you refer to are packaged as "jar" and do not supply "pom" packaging. See http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Dependencies, search for "Type".